# SQL Server : select/create duplicate rows with time shift [ reverse count() ]

Tags: sql-server, count, reverse

I am looking on rather CREATING duplicate rows using a SELECT query only on SQL Server, but can't figure it out how.

I have this:

```
datetime                | item  | count
2016-10-19 11:23:03.567 | X1    | 3
2016-10-19 11:43:07.340 | X2    | 1
2016-10-19 13:26:23.130 | X3    | 2
2016-10-19 15:15:14.960 | X4    | 5
```

And looking to get this:

```
datetime                | item
2016-10-19 11:23:03.567 | X1    
2016-10-19 11:23:03.568 | X1    
2016-10-19 11:23:03.569 | X1    
2016-10-19 11:43:07.340 | X2
2016-10-19 13:26:23.130 | X3
2016-10-19 13:26:23.131 | X3
2016-10-19 15:15:14.960 | X4
2016-10-19 15:15:14.961 | X4
2016-10-19 15:15:14.962 | X4
2016-10-19 15:15:14.963 | X4
2016-10-19 15:15:14.964 | X4
```

Basically I require one entry per each item in the count.

So if the count is 3, I need to get 3 rows as a result.

To differentiate I would also like to add 1 millisecond to each of the extra entries.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have a table that is just a bunch of numbers (1, 2, 3, etc.) then join to that based on your count and add your milliseconds based on the number.  The join will multiply the rows and the number associated with each joined row will allow you to compute the timestamp.

So something like this (assuming you don't have a numbers table already saved to your database):

```
--this creates a table with a ton of numbers
Pass0 as (select 1 as C union all select 1), --2 rows
Pass1 as (select 1 as C from Pass0 as A, Pass0 as B),--4 rows
Pass2 as (select 1 as C from Pass1 as A, Pass1 as B),--16 rows
Pass3 as (select 1 as C from Pass2 as A, Pass2 as B),--256 rows
Pass4 as (select 1 as C from Pass3 as A, Pass3 as B),--65536 rows
Pass5 as (select 1 as C from Pass4 as A, Pass4 as B),--4,294,967,296 rows
--add more numbers if you need them
Numbers as (select row_number() over(order by C) as val from Pass5)
select dateadd(millisecond, n.val - 1, t.datetime) as datetime
        , t.item
from myTable t
inner join Numbers n on n.val <= t.count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
--DROP TABLE #TEMP
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(id int, amount int, dateof datetime2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES (1, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES (4, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
*/
SELECT id, amount, datefinal = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, RN, dateof)--, dateof, RN
FROM (
    SELECT
        *, RN = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY NEWID()) - 1)
    FROM #TEMP
    JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)) AS T(C) ON C <= amount
) AS T
ORDER BY id, datefinal
```

Be *extremely* careful when using this with `datetime` data type, as it usually omits changes 1 millisecond small.

Answer (score 0):

This probably can be writen 10 times better but here is one way with currors and while loop

```
  declare  @table table
(dt datetime2 ,item varchar(3),cnt int)

declare  @table2 table
(dt datetime2 ,item varchar(3))

insert into @table
select '2016-10-19 11:23:03.567' , 'X1', 3
union all
select '2016-10-19 11:43:07.340' , 'X2'    , 1
union all
select '2016-10-19 13:26:23.130' , 'X3'    , 2
union all
select '2016-10-19 15:15:14.960' , 'X4'    , 5



declare @cnt int,@item varchar(3)
    ,@i int=0

declare @kurs cursor

set @kurs = cursor for
select item,SUM(cnt) from @table group by item

open @kurs 
fetch next from @kurs into @item,@cnt
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
    set @i=0
        while (@i<@cnt)
        begin
            insert into @table2
            select DATEADD(MILLISECOND,@i,dt),item  from @table where item=@item ;
            set @i=@i+1
        end
fetch next from @kurs into @item,@cnt
end

close @kurs

select * from @table2
```